# Binding redirects in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly, app-config, assembly-resolution

I have been trying to fix version conflicts in my .NET 6 console project. I fail to find a way like app.config's BindingRedirect or CodeBase, which worked  for this case in .NET Framework.

Is there a BindingRedirect/CodeBase or an alternative in .NET 6? How do I fix assembly version problems?

Comment: I believe you can just add the `app.config` and add a binding redirect.

Comment: @Stefan OP _"I believe you can just add the app.config and add a binding redirect"_ - OP has already indicated knowledge of _"app.config's BindingRedirect or CodeBase whiuch were in .Net Framework"_

Comment: @MickyD: yeah, so the `app.config` is default included in .net framework templates, but is missing in the .net core templates. Whilst OP indicates to have knowledge about the `app.config`, it's still ambiguous if OP knows he/she can just add the file.

Comment: @Stefan I'm pretty certain that's just going to get ignored. Binding redirects don't exist in .NET Core, it's a legacy .NET Framework thing.

Comment: @CharlesMager: than I was incorrect on that part - i.e.: I believed wrong XD

Comment: As I understand, app.config is not supported in .net core or later

Comment: Looks like there is no solution in .net core /5/6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies

Answer (score -5):

To update the version in console application
you can go to Explorer project files
Project => properties => AssemblyInfo.cs

[image]